# Editing JList in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable whose every cell contains a JList. What I want to do is to make that table editable so that every item on the JList can be edited either using a JTextfield or Choosing an item from another List whenever the user right clicks on that list item in a particular table cell. I also want 2 of my table column need to be set uneditable. Here is a picture of my JTable. I want the every cell and every JList item on that cell to be editable leaving the 'Batch' and 'Break' column to be uneditable.

P.S. I don't want any spoon fed code. I just want an idea how it can be done. And I'll be really grateful if you can reference me some link on the web where I can read to learn how this type of problems can be solved. Thank you..!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrqNX.jpg)

Comment: Since `JList` doesn't support editing, I think you'll find this task extremely difficult

Comment: Isnt it possible that when I right click on a list item a dialog appears to take input text from user, then I delele the item from the JList and insert the text provided by user at the same index of that JList?

Comment: Sure - but, for what it's worth, I think you're overcomplicating the problem - what's the reason for putting a `JList` in each cell?!

Comment: The problem is that you do not have a JList object in each of the cell. JTable creates (default behavior) a single JList object and uses it to render the cell. So you can't hook an event to the JList. What you may want to do is to listen to the mouse events on the JTable, construct a JList using the renderer for that cell, use the coordinates in the event to find the list item and then do whatever you need to do.

Comment: @madprogrammer Its because of the data structure i've used to generate the object which is populating the JTable. It seems from that picture that each item can be referenced to a different cell. But Surely it isnt the case. And I also wanted a multiline JTable so that filling up the JTable doesn't a become a hard task. Now my problem is whenever i do change the JList how can I make my TableModel to know about this event and change itself accordingly and fire a Table cell change operation.

Comment: Thank you. @KDM Sounds good. But I think I've run into trouble.